# Rendering with Three.js in vscode-extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, three.js, vscode-extensions

I am creating a `vscode` extension where I want to visualize 3D meshes. Below the function where I get the HTML content:

```js
function getWebviewContent(context: vscode.ExtensionContext, panel: vscode.WebviewPanel) {
      const threejs =  vscode.Uri.file(context.extensionPath+"/js/three.js");  
      const threejsUri = panel.webview.asWebviewUri(threejs);
      const geometryjs =  vscode.Uri.file(context.extensionPath+"/js/geometry.js");  
      const geometryjsUri = panel.webview.asWebviewUri(geometryjs);
      return `
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>My first three.js app</title>
          <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <script src=${threejsUri}></script>
          <script src=${geometryjsUri}></script>
        </body>
      </html>
      `
}
```

Now if my `geometry.js` is

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};
animate();
```

it works as expected. But if I make a class out of it:

```js
import { Scene, PerspectiveCamera, WebGLRenderer, BoxGeometry, MeshBasicMaterial, Mesh, requestAnimationFrame } from 'three';
class Viewer {
    constructor() {
        this.scene = new Scene();
        this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    
        this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
        this.geometry = new BoxGeometry();
        this.material = new MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
        this.cube = new Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );
        this.scene.add( cube );
    
        this.camera.position.z = 5;
    }
    
    animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( this.animate );
    
        this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    
        this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
    }
}

let viewer = new Viewer();
viewer.animate();
```

the HTML page is empty. What am I doing wrong here? I depend on an external package for rendering which uses classes,  so I need to understand how to properly create and use these classes here.

**Edit:** I have changed `geometry.js` to `typescript`, but still no luck

```js
import { Scene, PerspectiveCamera, WebGLRenderer, BoxGeometry, MeshBasicMaterial, Mesh } from 'three';

export class Viewer {
    private scene!: Scene;
    private camera: PerspectiveCamera;
    private renderer: WebGLRenderer;
    private geometry: BoxGeometry;
    private material: MeshBasicMaterial;
    private cube: Mesh;

    constructor(document: Document) {
        this.scene = new Scene();
        this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    
        this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );

        this.geometry = new BoxGeometry();
        this.material = new MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
        this.cube = new Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );
        this.scene.add( this.cube );
    
        this.camera.position.z = 5;
        this.animate();
    }
    
    public animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( this.animate );
    
        this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    
        this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
    }
}

new Viewer(document);
```

**Edit 2:** Oddly, something like this works

```js
function init() {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );

    camera.position.z = 5;

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };

    animate();
}

window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    init();
});
```

I don't understand what's happening here. Why does the `animate()` function has to be inside `init()`? In a class, isn't this achieved by using `this` for the members?

**Edit 3:**

```
class Viewer {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
        this.cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        this.scene.add( cube );
    
        this.camera.position.z = 5;
    
        this.boundAnimate = this.animate.bind(this);
        this.animate(); // this.boundAnimate();
    }
    
    animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.boundAnimate);
    
        this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    
        this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
    }
}

let viewer = new Viewer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` tries to call the provided function under the context of the `window` object (`this === window`).

When you run your code in a functional way (your original and edit 2 methods), some of the objects are scoped such that you still have access to them inside the `animate` function. But when you use the class, and `requestAnimationFrame` calls `this.animate`, it will work the first time, but the second time your `this` becomes `window` and your program has flown off the rails.

To correct this, I usually bind the function to a context to prevent an override. You can also `call` it directly and provide the context you want to use.

### Using function binding

```js
class MyClass{
  constructor(){
    this.boundAnimate = this.animate.bind(this);
  }

  animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(this.boundAnimate);
  }
};
```

### Using `call`

```js
class MyClass{
  animate(){
    window.prototype.requestAnimationFrame.call(this, this.animate);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have added "edit 3" which is still not working. I tried with both methods.

Comment: @harsh Strange. "Works on my machine." At least as far as `requestAnimationFrame` goes. If you're developing a plugin, you must have VSCode in debug mode... Can you open the console and ensure it's actually injecting the three.js canvas the way you expect it to? Also, you should be able to debug your plugin to ensure it's hitting your render loop.

Comment: I tried out the code here: https://codepen.io/ipa-hsd/pen/GROwvmX. You can see the console output, but the box is not visualized. And this is the original example which works: https://codepen.io/8Observer8/pen/oWoXyz?editors=1111

Comment: And finally worked! Couple of problems - I had not given dimensions to `BoxGeometry` (not sure why it worked when it was without the class). Second (not sure again), I had exported the class and imported `three` and instantiated in the same file. I removed `export`, removed `three` import, and it worked!